# Simple HTML DOM find multiple tags simultaneously

Tags: tags, simple-html-dom, simultaneous

I have a string:

```
<h2>header 1</h2>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<h2>header 2</h2>
<h3>siausjfks</h3>
....(anything not containing h2 and p tags)

<div><h2>header 3</h2> jasgfks</div>
.... (anything not containing h2 and p tags)
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Now i want to have array

```
element 1 = header 1
element 2 = paragraph 1
element 3 = header 2
element 4 = header 3
element 5 = paragraph 2
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using simple HTML DOM?

Thanks :)

UPDATE: This is actually to find 2 tags simultaneously, how about finding 3, 4 and more tags?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ Gunaseelan I have a quick dirty solution, by stripping all tags excepts h1,h2,h3,p before `str_get_html($str)`. That doesn't answer the original question, but it is temporarily working for me at this moment.

Comment: So, it's about finding all `h2` and `p` elements ? If so, `find("h2, p, X, Y, Z")` will return all the comma separated tags (X, Y, ...) for you in an array

Comment: I am surprised about its simplicity. Thank you Enissay. Can you write the answer for the question so that i can mark it as answered?